# Haskell, Stack, importing module shows error "Module not found"

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

If i write import in .hs file, it pops error saying no module found for "Lib" and "import Numeric.LinearAlgebra ( (><), linearSolve )". Also i got error saying ambiguous type.

src/Lib.hs

```
module Lib where
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra ( (><), linearSolve )


c = (2><2) [ 1.0, 2.0 , 3.0, 5.0 ]
d = (2><3) [ 6.0, 1.0, 10.0 , 15.0, 3.0, 26.0 ]


someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
    putStrLn "someFunc"
    print c
```

app/Main.hs

```
module Main (main) where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = someFunc
```

Error 1 : Could not find module "Numeric.LinearAlgebra" and "Lib"  (Error shows in VS code)

Error 2 : ambiguous type

```
I:\\haskellFiles\aet11\src\Lib.hs:5:6: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a1' arising from a use of `><'
      prevents the constraint `(Foreign.Storable.Storable
                                  a1)' from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        c :: hmatrix-0.20.2:Internal.Matrix.Matrix a1
          (bound at I:\\haskellFiles\aet11\src\Lib.hs:5:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a1' should be.
      These potential instances exist:   
        instance Foreign.Storable.Storable ()
          -- Defined in `Foreign.Storable'
        instance Foreign.Storable.Storable Bool
          -- Defined in `Foreign.Storable'
        instance Foreign.Storable.Storable Char
          -- Defined in `Foreign.Storable'
        ...plus four others
        ...plus 40 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances 
to see them all)
    * In the expression: 2 >< 2
      In the expression: (2 >< 2) [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
      In an equation for `c': c = (2 >< 2) [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ....]
  |
5 | c = (2><2) [ 1.0, 2.0 , 3.0, 5.0 ]   
  |      ^^^^

I:\\haskellFiles\aet11\src\Lib.hs:5:14: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a1' arising from the literal `1.0'
      prevents the constraint `(Fractional a1)' from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        c :: hmatrix-0.20.2:Internal.Matrix.Matrix a1
          (bound at I:\\haskellFiles\aet11\src\Lib.hs:5:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a1' should be.
      These potential instances exist:   
        instance Fractional Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        instance Fractional Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        ...plus six instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances 
to see them all)
    * In the expression: 1.0
      In the first argument of `2 >< 2', 
namely `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]'
      In the expression: (2 >< 2) [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
  |
5 | c = (2><2) [ 1.0, 2.0 , 3.0, 5.0 ]
```

However, if i import it only in ghci, that works just fine

[Image writing syntax directly in ghci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuutV.jpg)

I have tried using stack repl, stack ghci, stack build.
Tried reinstall Haskell, delete /sr/ and /Programs/stack/ and reinstall stack, reinstall vs code extension Haskell, Haskelly and Haskell Syntax Highlighting.
Didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, instead include error etc. messages in your post as screenshots. - For the problem: there are many similar questions on StackOverflow. Generally, you always need a `nameofyourproject.cabal` file in which dependencies are specified (in this case, [`hmatrix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix). Then compile your code with Cabal or Stack which are responsible for installing the dependencies. In turn, those should be installed using GHCup. _Don't_ manually install any packages.

Comment: I don't think i used stack install or cabal install tho. I put hmatrix in package.ymal as dependence, and flag openblas in stack.yaml. The package just installed automatically.

Comment: If you check out the error message, the problem is you're missing type annotations for an ambiguous type. Check out the duplicate question about ambiguous types for an explanation.